# Dotnet 6 Xunit integration testing EnsureSuccessStatusCode gives Response status code does not indicate success: 500

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xunit.net

Hello I'm learning integration testing and I want to test a 'POST' method from my controller using xunit and WebApplicationFactory But I'm getting this exception

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).

This is my Test:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace integrationtest.IntegrationTests;

public class ControllerTest  : IClassFixture<TestingWebAppFactory<Program>>
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    public ControllerTest(TestingWebAppFactory<Program> factory) 
        => _client = factory.CreateClient();

    

    [Fact]
    public async Task AddAccountTest()
    {
        var postRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/api/Accounts/Register");
        
        var formModel = new RegisterInputModel{
            UserName= "newuser111",
            Email = "newuser@example.com",
            PhoneNumber = "111222333",
            Password= "Gamma2205!",
            ConfirmPassword= "Gamma2205!"
            } ; 
        var stringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formModel);
        postRequest.Content = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


        var response = await _client.SendAsync(postRequest); 

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 
        response.IsSuccessStatusCode.Equals(true); 

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
        Assert.Contains("1", responseString); 
    }
}
```

This is my controller function

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Response>> Register(RegisterInputModel userRegiterModel)
        {
            HttpContext.Items.Add("action","Accounts.Register");
            await _accountsService.Register(userRegiterModel);
            return Ok(new ResponseSuccess("User Registered Successfully", "Accounts.Register"));
        }
```

This is the service

```
public async Task<IdentityResult> Register(RegisterInputModel userRegiterModel)
        {
        
            try
            {
                ApplicationUser registrationUser = new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    Email = userRegiterModel.Email,
                    UserName = userRegiterModel.UserName,
                    PhoneNumber = userRegiterModel.PhoneNumber
                };
               

                IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(registrationUser, userRegiterModel.Password);
                if (!result.Succeeded)
                {
                    IdentityErrorDescriber errorDescriber = new IdentityErrorDescriber();
                    IdentityError primaryError = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();

                    if (primaryError.Code == nameof(errorDescriber.DuplicateEmail))
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Email already exists.");
                    }
                    else if (primaryError.Code == nameof(errorDescriber.DuplicateUserName))
                    {
                        //_logger.LogError($"Username already exists: {registrationUser.UserName}");
                        throw new Exception("Username already exists.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception(primaryError.Description);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return result;
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Well that suggests that the server side of the code is throwing an exception. Are any errors logged? Have you stepped through the code?

Comment: It doesnt give me an exact error, even if my controller doesnt throw any error when i'm using postman or somthing

Comment: Again: have you stepped through the code? If you could provide a *complete* (but minimal) example, we could test it for ourselves of course - but without knowing anything about the code, all we can say is that it appears to be returning an HTTP 500 response, representing an internal error.

Comment: I added my controller and service to the post

Comment: Well, you've added the methods. It would still take significant effort for each person who wanted to help you to get to the stage of being able to run your code. And you *still* haven't answered whether you've stepped through the code in the debugger. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and try to improve your questions.